# Using ntp across LAN

Tags: networking, sync, lan, date, ntp

I have 3 debian computers connected to a network switch across LAN without WAN access.  I would like to **manually** set the date and time on one of the computers, then automatically sync the time to the other computers on my network.

I have followed some of the guides online, but they include syncing the master `ntp` server to another server across WAN.  Because my use case is different than the instructions, I am unsure if I followed them correctly and don't know how to individually troubleshoot the server and client.

Additionally, once the `ntp` server and clients are working, how do I manually set the time?  Is the time represented in `ntp` the same as date?

Answer (score 1):

You can teach ntpd to regard the host clock as "accurate".

```
server 127.127.1.1      # LCL, local clock
fudge  127.127.1.1 stratum 12   # increase stratum
```

See http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-refclk.htm